# ClamAV eating up all available disk space

Tags: linux, clamav

Today I found that my Redhat server has run out of hard disk space. The culprit seems to be a program called **Clamav** that fills /tmp directory with thousands of subfolders with names like `clamav-004adb870cd79534`. All these folders contain this:

```
    drwx------   2 root root 4.0K Apr 21 07:56 .
    drwxrwxrwt  68 root root  64K Apr 21 08:03 ..
    -rw-------   1 root root  18K Apr 21 07:56 COPYING
    -rw-------   1 root root 4.6M Apr 21 07:56 main.db
    -rw-------   1 root root  14K Apr 21 07:56 main.fp
    -rw-------   1 root root 1.5M Apr 21 07:56 main.hdb
    -rw-------   1 root root  901 Apr 21 07:56 main.info
    -rw-------   1 root root  33M Apr 21 07:56 main.mdb
    -rw-------   1 root root  16M Apr 21 07:56 main.ndb
    -rw-------   1 root root  217 Apr 21 07:56 main.zmd
```

When I deleted them they got back and filled my hard drive in about an hour again.

How do I go about this? Can I safely stop Clamav? It seems to me that Clamav is trying to upgrade unsuccessfully.

UPDATE:
I was able to sort this out after reading this topic:
http://forums.theplanet.com/index.php?showtopic=92267

I opened `/etc/MailScanner/MailScanner.conf` and commented out the following line:

```
Virus Scanners = clamavmodule
```

Then restarted MailScanner:

```
/sbin/service MailScanner restart
```

Answer (score 5):

You can limit disk usage of the temporary files when running clamscan, by using the --max-space flag like this

```
clamscan --max-space=50m --tempdir=/tmp/ --infected --recursive /home/
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check on the version of your ClamAV. Recently they stopped providing updated db files to version 0.94, so when your `freshclam` (the part that updates the definitions db) goes to download the update, instead of the expected result, if receives the error message, which may not play well with your `freshclam` and it tries to re-download the updates over and over again.